# jquery get img tag's height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find out the `width` and `height` of `img` tag. There's two cases:

If the image is **NOT** in cache, then this works fine:

```
            img.onload = function() {
                console.log('LOADED');
                var photoWidth = $photo.width();
                console.log("photo width: " + photoWidth);
            };
            img.src = $photo.get(0).src;
```

It properly logs the width of the `img` tag. Notice that I don't want the dimensions of the image, but the `img` tag.

The problem arsies if the image is already in the cache. Then the above code outputs `photo width: 0`.

This is because `onload` is called faster than the `img` tag is inserted into the `DOM`. (I think).

What are my alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: What means this: "*I don't want the dimensions of the image, but the img tag.*" ?

Comment: If the image is cached, the onload either fires right away and would give you the right answer, or not at all, it can't fire faster than the  image is inserted, as that's not possible.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the img tag's CSS max-width: 100%; which means it resizes itself. I want that size, not the actual image size.

Comment: That's something completely different than what you wrote in the question ?

Comment: Have you tried giving it some time by using `setTimeout` ?

Comment: As Adeneo says. If you want the image computed size you might be interested in `element.getBoundingClientRect()` `.width` and `.height` after you place it in it's DOM position

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VRMz7/1/

Comment: @adeneo his code runs, but it returns the wrong result..

Comment: @adeneo yes that's what happens...do you have any source or documentation that supports that claim? that it can't fire faster ?

Comment: Why are you not reading the width of img!

Comment: @epascarello the img tag's CSS max-width: 100%; which means it resizes itself. I want that size, not the actual image size.

Comment: See my fiddle, `clientWidth` gives you the actual width in the browser.

Comment: @adeneo like I said, this works ONLY if it's already in the DOM.

Comment: What do you mean already in the DOM, did you expect that this would work with images that are inserted dynamically later ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element's `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`.

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/gKGf6/1/)